# How does this oscillator circuit work? Inductor phase

Tags: transistors, capacitor, inductor, oscillator, npn

I simulated in it LTspice software. The voltage waveform across capacitor C4 was sinusoidal. I know its some kind of oscillator but don't know how it's operating?

I think the reason behind center tapped inductor is to create two inductors out of phase with each other but how does it happen? How are the inductors out of phase with each other?

[image: schematic]

Comment: Are the inductors L1 and L2 on the same core? If yes, you need a SPICE statement "k L1 L2 1".

Answer (score 2):

> *How does this oscillator circuit work?*

You should study Hartley and Colpitts oscillators: -

[image]

Image taken from [Wikipedia - Hartley oscillator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hartley_oscillator)

Your circuit is a Hartley oscillator and a slightly modified version of the one in the diagram from wiki. The centre node of the two inductors is connected to the positive supply in your diagram but, on the wiki diagram it connects to ground. Your diagram is the preferred implementation of this type of Hartley oscillator because it naturally passes DC bias currents to the transistor collector without the need for the choke.

> *How are the inductors out of phase with each other?*

You can simulate it and see that there is a significant phase change from input to output over a very small part of the spectrum (centred at 25 kHz): -

[image]

At about 25 kHz there is a phase change of 180° and, given that the transistor provides 180° (due to it being an inverting amplifier), you can see that there is a total phase shift of 360° and thus produces oscillation close to 25 kHz (because the gain is slightly above unity).

Comment: `Your diagram is the preferred implementation of this type of Hartley oscillator because it naturally passes DC bias currents to the transistor collector without the need for the choke.` the choke is there to isolate the DC from AC but the circuit still would work with a resistor instead of a chunky choke at the collector, if properly biased of course.

Comment: I'm unsure of the relevance of your comment @RohatKılıç

Comment: It was related to the last sentence of the 1st paragraph. Edited my comment.

Comment: Yes, I know where it came from but I don't understand the relevance of the comment or the point you are making  @Rohat

Comment: Are you saying that the wiki circuit could use a resistor instead of a choke because, if you are I agree.

Comment: Yeah, because IMO another reason of "preference" of the modified version is probably that no need of an extra choke *(all the grounded tank versions of Hartley are shown with a choke at the collector, making the extra magnetics count 2)* but it can still work with a resistor instead (oscillation amplitude would drastically be less, though). That is what I was trying to say. It sounds irrelevant, yes but glad you agree.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my short explanation:

The transistor has a finite (dynamic) output resistance r_out which - together with L2, L1 and C4 - forms a third-order highpass in ladder topology: r_out-L2-C4-L1 (terminology as given in the 1st circuit diagram).
Both inductors (L1 and L2) are grounded via C3 (resp. the DC source V1).

There is one single frequency fo at which the phase shift of this ladder highpass is exactly 180deg. This highpass network is connected (via C1) to the base node of the transistor (feedback). The additional phase shift of the common emitter configuration adds another 180deg to the phase - thus fulfilling Barkhausens loop phase  condition for oscillation at this specific frequency fo (zero phase shift at f=fo)

All other capacitors are coupling capacitors only and - if well designed - should not contribute too much to the phase shift and to the oscillating frequency.

Comment: nice to see you are still around on this forum sir

Comment: okay what i understood about this circuit is that at starting current flow voltage source to L1 charging C4 capacitor, R1 and C1. Because of it the transistor gets ON . Now the C4 capacitor discharged through lower plate through L2. Becasue of it upper plate of c4 and c1 generate a negetive voltage and transistor is OFF 
this is my understanding realted to this circuit 
can you please please help to understand this circuit from basic

Comment: It is really much easier to understand the function of such a circuit when you try to analyze it in the frequency domain (as I did) and NOT in the time domain (as you did in your comment). This is true for any electronic circuit that has intentionally a certain frequency-dependent characteristic like all filters and oscillators. More than that - specification as well as design steps and strageties for such circuits are all performed in the frequency domain only because we have to deal with sinusoidal signals only.